# How to create zip of multiple files (NOT FOLDER) in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have few files and few folders at IsolatedStorage and I want to zip it.
How can I do it? all the zipping library I have found are not compatible to WP8.

Comment: There is a port of SharpZipLib that is compatible with Windows Phone. http://nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib-WP7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the compression library (Nuget package: *Delay.GzipWebClient*) described in this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2012/04/19/quot-if-i-have-seen-further-it-is-by-standing-on-the-shoulders-of-giants-quot-an-alternate-implementation-of-http-gzip-decompression-for-windows-phone.aspx) which works in windows phone.